# Visual accept std::string from std::byte iterator

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, clang, language-lawyer

This code compile fine in Visual and failed in GCC or Clang.

I understand that the conversion from `std::byte` to `char` might be a problem. Is it forbidden to provide this conversion and is a visual C++ bug or is it acceptable and a nice feature missing from GCC/Clang?

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::byte> test(10);
    std::string str(test.begin(), test.end());
}
```

Edit

Microsoft [(fixed it)](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/337453/visual-accept-stdstring-from-stdbyte-iterator.html)

> We have fixed the problem in a future release. Now MSVC provide an
>   error like below: error C2664: 'void
>   std::basic_string,std::allocator>::push_back(const
>   _Elem)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::byte' to 'const _Elem' with [
>   _Elem=char ]

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I think the concern here is the discrepancy between Visual C++ and GCC and Clang.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude [`std::byte`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/byte) is distinct from the other types you mention in that it's isn't considered a character type and is not considered an integral type.

Comment: MS fails to compile [this code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7d64f8a27d72f761) so they must be doing something special to handle `std::byte`.

Comment: Are you using the /J (default char type is unsigned) compiler option? If I read this right it would allow this to compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSVS's string constructor that takes an iterator pair looks like

```
template<class _Iter,
    class = enable_if_t<_Is_iterator_v<_Iter>>>
    basic_string(_Iter _First, _Iter _Last, const _Alloc& _Al = _Alloc())
    : _Mybase(_Al)
    {   // construct from [_First, _Last) with optional allocator
    _Tidy_init();
    _Adl_verify_range(_First, _Last);
    _Construct(_Get_unwrapped(_First), _Get_unwrapped(_Last), _Iter_cat_t<_Iter>());
    }
```

And `_Construct` eventualy calls

```
template<class _Iter>
    void _Construct(_Iter _First, const _Iter _Last, input_iterator_tag)
    {   // initialize from [_First, _Last), input iterators
    _TRY_BEGIN
    for (; _First != _Last; ++_First)
        {
        push_back(static_cast<_Elem>(*_First));
        }

    _CATCH_ALL
    _Tidy_deallocate();
    _RERAISE;
    _CATCH_END
    }
```

With the important bit being `push_back(static_cast<_Elem>(*_First));`.  Normally you would not be able to assign a `std::byte` directly to another type since it is a scoped enumeration but since there is a `static_cast` you get around that. 
 This is why you are able to use a range of bytes to initialize a `std::string`.

That said the iterator constructor requires from [[sequence.reqmts] - Table 68](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/sequence.reqmts#tab:containers.sequence.requirements) that

> `T` shall be EmplaceConstructible into `X` from `*i`.

and [[container.requirements.general]/15.5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/container.requirements.general#15.5) states that `EmplaceConstructible` means

> `T` is EmplaceConstructible into `X` from `args` , for zero or more arguments `args`, means that the following expression is well-formed:
>
> ```
> allocator_traits<A>::construct(m, p, args)
> ```

and `construct` is defined in [[allocator.requirements] - Table 33](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/allocator.requirements#tab:utilities.allocator.requirements) as

> Effects: Constructs an object of type C at c
>
> Default `::new ((void*)c)C(forward<Args>(args)...)`

So it is still unclear if this is allowed or not.

Comment: I read this through a second time following through the standard language chain to `Effects: Constructs an object of type C at c`. After thinking a while I don't see any indication that `Constructs an object` would leave open a gap for special-case conversions to be added by an implementation, especially corroborated by the fact that the default implementation doesn't allow such things.

Comment: char was signed so it looks like a bug to me to convert std::byte to char

Answer (score 1):

Visual C++ is wrong. `std::byte` is a scoped enumeration, *i.e.,* declared as if by `enum class`, and therefore cannot be converted to `char` or any other arithmetic type unless an explicit cast is used.